# how to run a method in another thread in rxjava

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have written the following code using Rxjava2:

```
public class RxSchTest {

    public Observable<String> validate(String str){

        return Observable.create(s->{

            s.onNext(str+":v1");
            System.out.println("run on threads "+Thread.currentThread());
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void testbackRun(){
       // Observable<String>
        for(int i =0;i<10;i++) {
            validate("test"+i).observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(System.out::println);
        }

    }
}
```

the output is unexpected:

> run on threads Thread[main,5,main]
>
> test0:v1
>
> run on threads Thread[main,5,main]
>
> test1:v1 run on threads Thread[main,5,main]
>
> test2:v1
>
> run on threads Thread[main,5,main]
>
> test3:v1
>
> run on threads Thread[main,5,main]
>
> test4:v1
>
> run on threads Thread[main,5,main]
>
> test5:v1
>
> run on threads Thread[main,5,main]
>
> test6:v1
>
> run on threads Thread[main,5,main]
>
> test7:v1
>
> run on threads Thread[main,5,main]
>
> test8:v1
>
> run on threads Thread[main,5,main]
>
> test9:v1

why all the observer are running on the main thread?

Answer (score 2):

You're creating your `Observable` on default (main) thread and **after** that you're switching thread to `io`. So only subscriber's printing happens on `io`. Remember, `observeOn` operator switches downstream thread.

If you need to subscribe your `Observable` on `io` use `subscribeOn` operator instead of `observeOn`.

```
@Test
public void testbackRun(){
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++) {
        validate("test"+i)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) <---------------
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

In this case, the whole stream will happen on `io` thread.

Comment: Just for complement, multi `subscribeOn()` won't work, all streams will work on the first `subscribeOn()` 's  scheduler. More details in this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdmkXL7XikQ